# NativeActivty will not start - Unable to load native library

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, native-activity, vs-android

I created another question because all of the others were answered with a solution that was similar but unrelated.  I have also ensured that it's not a symbol stripping issue.

I'm getting the dreaded error:

```
D/AndroidRuntime(16487): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(16487): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b1b700)
E/AndroidRuntime(16487): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(16487): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.test/android.app.NativeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/app-lib/com.test.test-1/libtest.so
E/AndroidRuntime(16487):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
E/AndroidRuntime(16487):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
...
```

Everything compiles and links just fine.

I also have app_dummy() and it's producing it properly as when I run with objdump I get it:

```
001186f4 g    DF .text  000001a4 ANativeActivity_onCreate
```

If it matters, using vs-android with toolchain 4.7.2, targeting 2.3.3 (android-10), for armv7-a.  I have libraries that I include appropriately, and end up fully linking.

My one theory, which I'm still unable to prove, is that there are some .so files that I also need to include with the apk.  I assumed that the external libraries (so) would be merged with my own.  If this is not the case, this would likely explain the issue at hand.

I am not using any makefiles directly - vs-android is handling most of it.  I only have access to some .xml and .property files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this error will come up ambiguously if there are dependant libraries that cannot be found.  Since I'm using vs-android, I'm still unsure how to even get the external .so files to properly be included in the apk under the `/libs/` path.

The only solution to include external .so files is to somehow get the libraries into your apk and link them manually within code, call `System.loadLibrary()` on the Java side before your native library gets loaded, or have one native library load the libraries and then launch your main library.